# accsessing ascii direct

Tags: ascii

in widows I used to open any txt editor - set Numlock active and while holding Alt using the number pad type 0169 and get the ascii copyright © - How do I get direct ascii access in Linux / Ubuntu Studio Using Mousepad or any txt editor?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses unicode
The copyright sign **©** unicode is U+00A9
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, see an underlined `u`
Then type `00A9` and get the magic

Find all unicodes 
 - gnome-characters app
 - https://unicode-table.com/

Comment: For the Left Curly Bracket `{`, press `<Ctrl>`+`<Shift>`+`U`, then `7B`

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41418/how-to-be-more-productive-in-ubuntu-using-keyboard-shortcuts/ may also be helpful