# How do I use Windows shortcuts in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, windows, shortcuts

I am new to Ubuntu. I want to ask if it is possible to use the same Windows shortcuts in Ubuntu. For example, when I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> in Windows, I create a left curly brace.

Comment: That is not a keyboard shorcut. Find the answer to your question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157706/accsessing-ascii-direct/1157730#1157730

Comment: Typing the unicode feels really tedious, is there a faster way?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en

Comment: What is your standard keyboard (which language)? There might be a convenient way around the corner.

Comment: There are more than 100k characters in Unicode. Which ones are you frequently using?

Comment: I already got most of the answers i need, tho getting used to English keyboard layout is hard...

Comment: My standart keyboard layout is Czech